# How to revert both local and remote git repository to a previous commit?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, git-commit

I want every commit after the one with hash `ac9edf2` to disappear entirely from my local repository and the one on Github.

Trying to following instructions based on previous answers is like trying to study arcane magic.  For each step forward I run into a new error, or make some unwanted change I did not intend because the instructions are confusing, and commands are not intuitively named.

I just want something to copy and paste into the command line so that I can rewind reality 3 hours ago (specifically, to that commit) so that neither my local harddrive or the Github website knows about the alternate universe where I made commits after `ac9edf2`.

And I need it to be such that after I copy and paste these commands into the command line and hit ENTER, I can resume committing via MSVSC as usual, and be able to press `CTRL + G` then click `Publish branch` as usual to upload my new commits to Github without getting any deadly fatal errors.

I don't want to become a git expert.  I don't need to be concerned about any non-existent collaborators losing their work.  I just want to go back in time to the commit `ac9edf2`.  Forever.

Comment: You could do without all the editorializing in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your local machine, with your master branch checked out (presumably that's what you want to fix up, right?):

```
$ git reset --hard ac9edf2
$ git push -f
```

This answer does assume that your local branch is checked out as a tracking branch.